# Is it possible to do a "LIMIT 1" on a left join in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables: one for money and attributes surrounding it (e.g. who earnt it) and a child table for the "ledger" - this contains one or more entries that represent the history of money that has moved.

```sql
SELECT SUM(pl.achieved)
FROM payout p
LEFT JOIN payout_ledgers pl ON pl.payout_id = p.id
```

This query works well when there is only one ledger item, but when more are added the `SUM` will increase. I want to join only the latest row. So hypothetically:

```sql
SELECT SUM(pl.achieved)
FROM payout p
LEFT JOIN payout_ledgers pl ON pl.payout_id = p.id ORDER BY pl.ts DESC LIMIT 1
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT ...
```

(which sadly doesn't work)

**What I have tried:**

Using a subquery works, but is painfully slow given the size of the data set (and other omitted properties and where clauses etc.):

```sql
SELECT SUM(pl.achieved)
FROM payout p
LEFT JOIN payout_ledgers pl ON pl.payout_id = p.id AND pl.id = (SELECT id FROM payout_ledgers WHERE payout_id = p.id ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Incidentally, I'm unsure why this subquery is so slow (~12 seconds, as opposed to 150ms with no subquery). I would have expected it to be quicker given that we're only selecting based on the foreign key (`payout_id`).

Another thing I tried was to do a select from the join - my logic being that if we select from small joined dataset instead of the whole table it would be quicker. However I was met with `relation "pl" does not exist` error:

```sql
SELECT SUM(pl.achieved)
FROM payouts p
LEFT JOIN payout_ledgers pl ON pl.payout_id = p.id
WHERE pl.id = (SELECT id FROM pl ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions. I am also open to suggestions for schema changes that could make this type of logic easier, although my preference would be to try and get the query working since the schema is not easy to change on our production environment.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a MySQL 5 query to PostgreSQL? In MySQL 8 and PosrgreSQL you can use the `LAST_VALUE` function to return the last value in a set , eg `SUM(LAST_VALUE(pl.achieved) OVER(ORDER BY pl.ts desc))`. The queries are slow because the inner query has to be executed for every outer row

Comment: Use a window function, such as `row_number()` BTW: why do you want to `SUM()` one item?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your suggestion. It seemed promising but unfortunately I am getting the error `aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls`.

Comment: @wildplasser Thank you for your suggestion. I am familiar with `row_number()` but where exactly would it fit into the query? I need to sum only one item since the child relation `payout_ledgers` has one or more entries where only the latest one is the current representative state of the money (so that we essentially have a history of how money was moved)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Postgres 9.4+, you can use a `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html))

```
SELECT SUM(sub.achieved)
FROM payout p
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT achieved 
     FROM payout_ledgers pl 
     WHERE pl.payout_id = p.id 
     ORDER BY pl.ts DESC LIMIT 1) sub ON true
```

This will return the sum of the "achieved" field in the most recent entry in payout_ledgers for all payouts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did just give this a try and unfortunately it seems identically slow to having a subquery in the where. The speed of the query only changes when I add the `order by` and `limit`.

Comment: The slowness is not caused by a subquery (maybe it is/was in mysql, but not in Postgres) It is caused by lack of an index on (pl.payout_id, pl.ts)

Comment: @ollie do you have a suitable index?

Comment: My mistake, I believe this is to do with indexing. So for this subquery what would be the most suitable index? Do I have to do some kind of combo-index?

Comment: I agree with @wildplasser, if this query is very slow it's most likely due to the lack of a suitable index, try defining one on (pl.payout_id, pl.ts), postgres is usually pretty good at optimizing LATERAL queries

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you everyone! Creating the index on `payout_id` and `ts` worked an absolute charm + the lateral join subquery. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

window functions:

---

```
-- using row_number()
SELECT SUM(sss.achieved)
FROM (SELECT pl.achieved
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY pl.payout_id, ORDER BY pl.ts DESC)
        FROM payouts p
        JOIN payout_ledgers pl ON pl.payout_id = p.id
        ) sss
WHERE sss.rn =1
        ;
-- using last_value()
SELECT SUM(sss.achieved)
FROM (SELECT 
        , last_value(achieved) OVER (PARTITION BY pl.payout_id, ORDER BY pl.ts ASC) AS achieved
        FROM payouts p
        JOIN payout_ledgers pl ON pl.payout_id = p.id
        ) sss
        ;
```

---

BTW: you do not need the **LEFT** JOIN (adding no value to the SUM does not change the sum)